# How to redirect one category to sub category?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is FrontController

```
public function index(){
    $categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->select('category')
        ->groupBy('category')
        ->get();
    return view('front', compact('categories'));
}
```

This is blade layout

```html
@foreach($categories as $category)
<a href=""><h2 class="card-title">{{$category->category}}</br></h2></a>
@endforeach
```

[image: Categories-table structure and data]

[image: This is my front page]

My question is when i click any category redirect to related to subcategory...How can i do that??

Comment: You can put the category id in your link then use new URL to get the value of id and show subcategories on a new page.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it..bcoz id is random ,how can i do that through id? -@Rezasys

Comment: I'll post an answer to clarify it.

Comment: Yes you are right...May be my table structure is wrong -@Rezasys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your controller**, you can do the following:

```
// for categories
public function index() {
    $categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->select('category')
        ->groupBy('category')
        ->get();
    return view('front', compact('categories'));
}

// for sub categories
public function subCategory($category) {
    $sub_categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->where('category', $category)
        ->get();
    return view('another_front', compact('sub_categories'));
}
```

**In your blade:**

```
// for category
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <a href="{{ url('/subcategory') }}/{{$category->category}}"><h2 class="card-title">{{$category->category}}</br></h2></a>
@endforeach

// for sub category
@foreach($sub_categories as $subcategory)
        <a href="#"><h2 class="card-title">{{$subcategory->sub_category}}</br></h2></a>
    @endforeach
```

And the **Route** is:

```
Route::get('/subcategory/{category}', 'FrontController@subCategory');
```

Comment: Error occur -  Undefined variable: sub_categories (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\resources\views\front.blade.php) -

Comment: You can make different view for showing sub categories.

Comment: Should i create another view page of subcategory right? -

Comment: Yes, right you can make another view........ if you show sub category on the same view you can use isset function

Comment: <a href="{{route('subcategory.subCategory}')}}"><h2 class="card-title">{{$category->category}}</br></h2></a>
 this is url and i created subcategory.blade.php than show me error Route [subcategory.subCategory}] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\resources\views\front.blade.php)

Comment: you can use {{ url('/subcategory') }}/ {{$category->category}} instead of {{route('subcategory.subCategory}')}}

Comment: it show nothing and url show like this http://localhost:8000/subcategory/%20Bikes

Comment: remove space between the url and category name ..........  {{ url('/subcategory') }}/ {{$category->category}} after the **slash** space found.......... you can remove it {{ url('/subcategory') }}/{{$category->category}}

Comment: When i click subcategory than show all post related to caategory...but it's not display..how can i fetch? bcoz id is not giving proper.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

This is route file "web.php"

`project_url /category/{catid}`

This is blade layout

`@foreach($categories as $category)
    <a href="{{project url / category/$category->id}}"><h2 class="card-title">{{$category->category}}</br></h2></a>
@endforeach`